# Navigation Controller Issue ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

When i run my app in ios 8 everything works fine but when i run it on ios 7 the navigation bars dont show up.  I double checked that i have the navigation controller embed and i do with my view controller.  I use segues in the storyboard and some segues are coded because i have to wait for something to be done before you go to the next screen. As anyone else experienced this issue with the navigation bars not showing up on one version but shows up on another? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Code i use to segue in my code:

```
let vc : UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as UIViewController;
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: current view controller is in a Navigation controller? Then only you can push another view controller to show.

Comment: navigation controller root view is my view controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this in secondview controller -

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(true)  
      self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Can you check whether viewWillAppear getting called or not? Also I have edited my answer so try adding that.

Comment: thank you for your help i decided to do all my segues in the storyboard and that fixed the problem. Thanks again for your help